# Can I use Koin's 'by sharedViewModel' from java?

Tags: java, android, koin

I have an existing android java project where I am introducing Koin for DI.

In my activity I have been using

```
private Lazy<DeckActivityViewModel> viewModel = inject(DeckActivityViewModel.class);
```

I want to share the viewmodel across multiple fragments, so wonder if there is a java equivalent of 'by sharedViewModel()' to do so?

Answer (score 1):

For your Java `Fragment`, must be used `sharedViewModel` or `getSharedViewModel` from `SharedViewModelCompat`:

```
 private Lazy<DeckActivityViewModel> viewModel = SharedViewModelCompat.sharedViewModel(this, DeckActivityViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

Java doesn't support property delegation while koin is using property delegation to provide methods like `inject()`, `viewModel()` and `sharedViewModel()`. So, the answer is you cannot use it in java.

Comment: Is it helpful? Please mark it as right answer if it answers your question,